# How to use facebook connect in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have looked at the facebook iphone api and watched the tutorial they offer but an not sure if one needs to have a facebook app as well to be able to connect an iphone app to facebook.

I would like to allow my users to be able to share things on their profile. e.g. set their status from within my iphone app.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Facebook iPhone SDK](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_iPhone_SDK)

--edit--

You need to register your application to use the API.
[Authentication Docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Comment: I have. Does one need to have a facebook app?

Comment: No you don't have to create a facebook app to use facebook connect on the iPhone. You do need to register though to get the your client ids/key etc